# SharePoint solution - link access code-behind C# method

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, hyperlink, codebehind

I have a SharePoint solution with a link and a C# method.
There is any way I can access the C# method from the a tag:

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onclick="MyFunction()">CLICK</a>
public void MyFunction()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onclick="MyFunction()">CLICK</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
public void MyFunction()
{
      var temp = '<%=CodeBehindMethod()%>';
}
</script>
```

Code Behind Method

```
public void CodeBehindMethod() 
{
      //Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinkButton and use its onClick event:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="CLICK" OnClick="MyFunction()" runat="server"/>
```

and in the code behind use

```
public void MyFunction(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

}
```